# Jsoup table parsing

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I am new to jsoup and this parsing thingy, so if you need more information for you to be able to answer my question, just tell me!

I have this table that I want to parse using Jsoup in Java. I just want to get the text of:

"B S Computer Science , CS (2012-2014)"

from this part of the table

```
  <h3>Fahran S Kamili (fsk226)</h3>
        <div>
            10 Degree Audit Requests Returned.
        </div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
<!-- *nrfkh - 9/2012: [degaudt-634]* -->
                        <th colspan="8">Degree Audits Requested</th>

<!-- *end nrfkh - 9/2012: [degaudt-634]* -->

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Rerun</th>

<!-- *nrfkh - 9/2012: [degaudt-634]* -->

<!-- *end nrfkh - 9/2012: [degaudt-634]* -->
                    <th>Request Created</th>
<!-- *nrfkh - 9/2012: [degaudt-634]* -->

<!-- *end nrfkh - 9/2012: [degaudt-634]* -->
                    <th>Audit Type</th>
                    <th>Program</th>
                    <th>Courses Requested</th>
                    <th>Request Status</th>
                    <th>Audit ID</th>
                    <th>Delete Option</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td>
                                    <a href="https://utdirect.utexas.edu/apps/degree/audits/requests/student_individual/?form-0-eid=fsk226&form-0-name=Fahran%20S%20Kamili&form-0-begin_ccyy=2012&form-0-degree_plan=ESC%20SS%20CS&form-0-minor=&current=X&future=&planned=&form-TOTAL_FORMS=20&form-INITIAL_FORMS=0&form-MAX_NUM_FORMS=&rerun=" target="_blank">Rerun</a>
                        </td>
<!-- *nrfkh - 9/2012: [degaudt-634]* -->
<!-- *end nrfkh - 9/2012: [degaudt-634]* -->
                        <td>
                            12/20/2013
                            05:06 PM
                        </td>
<!-- *nrfkh - 9/2012: [degaudt-634]* -->
<!-- *end nrfkh - 9/2012: [degaudt-634]* -->
                        <td>
                                Normal

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            B S Computer Science, CS
                            (2012-2014)
                        </td>
```

The table actually is stretch down long but the contains are just siblings to each other (so I assume if I can get this text, I also can get the other text easily).

Comment: `"so if you need more information..."` -- yes, like what have you tried so far, and how is it not working? Also what is confusing you specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I save your part of `HTML` to a file and parse it through `jsoup`, I would try to print all `td` elements encountered since that is what you are after:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        File input = new File("C:/users/XYZ/desktop/input.html");
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "");
        Elements tds = doc.getElementsByTag("td");
        for (Element td : tds) {
            System.out.println(td.text());
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Rerun
12/20/2013 05:06 PM
Normal
B S Computer Science, CS (2012-2014)
```